# How to handle documents that contain fields with a null value in firestore?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever I query documents that contain an "address" field that is null, swift skips past the document in that collection. I am loading the fields from all the documents in the collection and if there is a null value then it skips the entire document.

Here is my struct:

```
protocol MealplanSerializable {
init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Mealplan {
var addressOne: String? = ""
var mpName:String

var Dictionary:[String : Any] {
    return [
        "addressOne": addressOne ?? "",
        "mpName": mpName
    ]
}
}

extension Mealplan : MealplanSerializable {
init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
    guard let addressOne = dictionary["addressOne"] as? String,
        let mpName = dictionary["mpName"] as? String


    else { return nil }

    self.init(addressOne: addressOne, mpName: mpName)
}
}
```

How do I specify the variables above to ensure that I read the fields irrespective of whether they are null or string?

Comment: What is the query that you are using? Please also add your database structure as a screenshot.